# Unable to apply dataformat string to Bound columns of datagrid generated dynamically

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

following is sample code i am trying to make work. 
i want to apply formatting to datagrid column "price" i want price to be shown in currency format

```
Dim bColumn As BoundColumn
        bColumn = New BoundColumn
        bColumn.HeaderText = "name"
        bColumn.DataField = "name"
        dgBizDocs.Columns.Add(bColumn)

        bColumn = New BoundColumn
        bColumn.HeaderText = "price"
        bColumn.DataField = "price"
        bColumn.DataFormatString = "{0:C}" ' already tried following "{0:#,##0.00}"
        dgBizDocs.Columns.Add(bColumn)

        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Columns.Add("name")
        dt.Columns.Add("price")

        Dim dr As DataRow
        dr = dt.NewRow
        dr("name") = "ABC"
        dr("price") = 1232100.53
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)

        dr = dt.NewRow
        dr("name") = "ABC"
        dr("price") = 123123.32
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)
        dt.AcceptChanges()
        dgBizDocs.DataSource = dt
        dgBizDocs.DataBind()
```

what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you try setting type of `price` column to `decimal` in datatable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the price column as decimal in datatable. You will get your formatting (tested).